# what are all the angular.json options in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6

The Angular-CLI Documentation does not seem contain a full reference to the schema of the angular.json, is there any place to find a more complete list of available options?

Comment: Please  refer the docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little digging I found the Schema Reference for the angular.json file inside the @Angular/cli github repo at

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace (no longer working, see update below)

#### Schema of schema.json:

Some of the options inside the angular.json file reference schema files. The schema of schema.json files can be found at http://json-schema.org/.

#### Update

The original link no longer works. The (archived) version of the angular.json schema is [still available](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/068bb4001d5d011bc1e9029ce620d8e197efa1b1/docs/documentation/angular-workspace.md).

However, an updated description is accessible via the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#overall-json-structure).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jens 
It's useful but it doesn't provide details of each option.
Is there any document/tutorial that provides more details about each option ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no documentation that gets more in-depth than the provided link, what descriptions are you missing?

Comment: For example, 'format' option lists enums which can be configurable but there are no details on how those options should be used or how it works etc.

Comment: There is no 'format' key in these options, what are you refering to ?

Comment: I was checking the default schematics of '@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint' and it's related options.

Comment: In that case, you're looking for the schema of a schema.json, check http://json-schema.org/

Comment: Ok how about outputhashing?

Comment: @gyozokudor I think you may want to create a separate question